# continue buffer in new window

Tags: vim-windows, scrolling

Let's say that I have a file which contains numbers from 1 to 200. Each number is on a separate line. As I have a wide screen, then I view this file in a way that I vertically split the window(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>), `:set scb` in first window, move to second window(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>), scroll down(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, etc) as much as first line in this second window is the last line + 1 of the first window and set the `scrollbind` in this second window. As a last step I move back to first window(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>). This works beautifully, but it is inconvenient to set up. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for DrChip's [mpage.vim](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#MPAGE) plugin:

*The mpage.vim plugin supports using multiple windows as separate pages to view a buffer (ie. file), with each window under mpage control sequentially showing lines of text.*